# How can I import the Turtle Module in a class?

Tags: python, class, turtle-graphics

I am drawing fractal trees in python and this is my method (it works):

```
def fractal(length):
    if lenght < 1:
        return
    else:
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(30)
        fractal(length*0.67)
        turtle.right(60)
        fractal(length*0.67)
        turtle.left(30)
        turtle.backward(length)
```

Now I am trying to implement this in a class but I don't know how I should do this with the turtle commands.

I am new to coding so please don't judge me too hard for my code.

I tried something like this:

```
class fractalTree():

from turtle import *

def __init__(self, angle, factor):
    self.angle = angle
    self.factor = factor

def fractal(self, length):
    if length < 1:
        return
    else:
        self.turtle.forward(length)
        self.turtle.left(self.angle)
        fractal(length * self.factor)
        self.turtle.right(self.angle * 2)
        fractal(length * self.factor)
        self.turtle.left(self.angle)
        self.turtle.backward(length)

test = fractalTree(14, 2/3)
test.fractal(100)
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? Have you tried to integrate this code in something bigger that uses classes? Or do you just want to use a class for the sake of using a class? Please give us a bigger picture!

Comment: I just want to use a calss for the sake of using a class. My exact Problem is that I dont know how to import the turtle module in a class.

Comment: You don't have to import anything in a class. Just keep importing `turtle` the way you do, with `import turtle` at the start of your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Its working now and I am happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can go about this.  Your custom class could *contain* a turtle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class fractalTree():

    def __init__(self, angle, factor):
        self.angle = angle
        self.factor = factor
        self.turtle = Turtle()

    def fractal(self, length):
        if length < 1:
            return

        self.turtle.forward(length)
        self.turtle.left(self.angle)
        self.fractal(length * self.factor)
        self.turtle.right(self.angle * 2)
        self.fractal(length * self.factor)
        self.turtle.left(self.angle)
        self.turtle.backward(length)

screen = Screen()

screen.mode('Logo')  # being lazy, make the tree upright

test = fractalTree(30, 2 / 3)

screen.tracer(False)
test.fractal(100)
screen.tracer(True)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Or, your custom class could *become* a turtle:

```
class fractalTree(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, angle, factor):
        super().__init__()
        self.angle = angle
        self.factor = factor

    def fractal(self, length):
        if length < 1:
            return

        self.forward(length)
        self.left(self.angle)
        self.fractal(length * self.factor)
        self.right(self.angle * 2)
        self.fractal(length * self.factor)
        self.left(self.angle)
        self.backward(length)
```

Or, you can do as you seem to be doing and have your custom class just use a turtle.

[image]